# lldb: How to remove a symbolic breakpoint?

Tags: xcode, debugging, lldb, xcode9.1

I've created breakpoint per this
[lldb breakpoint on all methods in class objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29687504/lldb-breakpoint-on-all-methods-in-class-objective-c)

> (lldb) breakpoint set -r '[UINavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:]'
>   Breakpoint 100: 5 locations.

but

> (lldb) breakpoint delete '[UINavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:]'
>   0 breakpoints deleted; 0 breakpoint locations disabled.

The newly created breakpoint[s] does not appear in the list
of breakpoints in xcode.

How could I get rid of it[them]??????

Answer (score 0):

had to remove by breakpoint #
after listing breakpoints

> breakpoint list