# LLDB Breakpoint on all methods in Swift class

Tags: swift, lldb

How can I use LLDB to set a breakpoint on all methods / computed properties in a Swift class?

My use case is to debug the flow of executing a particular type’s methods but we could also use the command for general debugging/learning.

I found the syntax to create an LLDB breakpoint for all methods in an Objective-C class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29687504/lldb-breakpoint-on-all-methods-in-class-objective-c), but this doesn't seem to work for Swift classes/structs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following syntax works for creating a Regex breakpoint for every symbol (properties and methods) in a Swift type, including `struct`s and `class`es.

Assuming a type called `Circle`:

```
(lldb) break set -r "\.Circle\..*"
```